# Creating lists to write to files error list index out of range

Tags: python

I am creating a list of file names.

```
self.hostTestFiles = ["hostTest1_ms.dat","hostTest2_ms.dat","hostTest3_ms.dat","hostTest4_ms.dat",
                          "hostTest5_ms.dat", "hostTest6_ms.dat","hostTest7_ms.dat","hostTest8_ms.dat",
                          "hostTest9_ms.dat","hostTest10_ms.dat"]
```

Then create another list for the path to the files.

```
self.hostFilePaths = []

for i in self.hostFilePaths:
        os.path.join(self.hostFolder, self.hostTestFiles[i])
```

I have a function that writes random data to each file, however it is saying that list index out of range

```
def createFile (self):
    print "creating file"
    for item in self.hostFilePaths:
        with open(item, 'wb') as fout:
            fout.write(os.urandom(10567))
            fout.flush()
            os.fsync(fout.fileno())
```

Then I want to copy these files from my computer to a usb and rename on usb but this doesnt seem to work either. 
Could anyone point me to where I am going wrong?

```
 self.usbFilePaths = []
 self.newUsbFilePaths = []


 for i in self.usbFilePaths:
        os.path.join(self.usbFolder, self.hostTestFiles[i])
 for i in self.newUsbFilePaths:
        os.path.join(self.usbFolder, self.usbTestFiles[i])


 def copyToUsb (self):
    print "Copying file from comp to usb"
    for item in self.hostFilePaths:
        shutil.copy(item, self.usbFolder)
        time.sleep(4)
    for i in range(0,10):
        print "here 2"
        shutil.move(self.usbFilePaths[i], self.newUsbFilePaths[i])
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: When you iterate over self.hostFilePaths or self.usbFilePaths or self.newUsbFilePaths, are they empty?

Comment: yes they are when i am creating the paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of how the python `for` works is a bit lacking.

```
for i in self.hostFilePaths:
    os.path.join(self.hostFolder, self.hostTestFiles[i])
```

Does not populate `self.hostFilePaths` with the result of the `os.path.join` operation, it stays empty and causes your index out of range errors. It should read

```
for i in self.hostTestFiles:
    self.hostFilePaths.append(os.path.join(self.hostFolder, i))
```

Alternatively, and more pythonic, you can do this with a list comprehension.

```
self.hostFilePaths = [ os.path.join(self.hostFolder, i) for i in self.hostTestFiles ]
```

You're making the same mistake in creating the usb file lists too.

Comment: Ok thank you just started using python so a lot to learn. So in my create file function how would I implement this or is what I'm doing correct.

Comment: @homeGrown createFile looks ok, although I don't think you need to flush all the things, since the file gets closed and flushed automatically with the with statement.